# Adding headings to Word document created with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have VBA code in an Excel workbook (.xlsm) that creates an Appendix as a Word document from the worksheets in that workbook.

I modified code from this site: https://hackernoon.com/how-to-create-word-documents-within-excel-vba-d13333jl

I am bolding some parts and changing the font size. I want to make them real headings.

In this code and where it says .BoldRun, I would like to say something like ".Heading 1" or ".Heading 2." but Word doesn't recognize those objects.
There is a .HeaderFooter object. There is a .SoryByHeaders method but no obvious way to create text as a heading.

How do I make the bolded text in the sample code below into "Headings" at level 1, 2, 3?

```vb
Sub create_word_document()

    Dim lead As String
    
    Dim app As word.Application
    Set app = New word.Application
    app.Visible = True
    app.Activate
    
    start_index = 1
    With app
        Category = 0
        .Visible = True
        .Activate
        .Documents.Add
        
        With .Selection
            .Style = wdStyleHeading1
            .TypeText Trim(Str(start_index)) & " Appendix Name"
            .TypeParagraph
            For i = 1 To 20
                .TypeText "Ipsum Lorem"
            Next i
            .TypeParagraph
            
            For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
                If sht.Name <> "Completion Index" And sht.Name <> "For Coding" Then
                    Category = Category + 1
                    
                    lead = Trim(Str(start_index)) & "." & Trim(Str(Category))
                    .Style = wdStyleHeading2
                    .TypeText lead & " " & sht.Name

                    .TypeParagraph
                    '.TypeText "Definition words for category"
                    .TypeParagraph
                    
                    For r = 2 To 50
                        If sht.Cells(r, 1).Value <> "" Then
                            inspection_name = sht.Cells(r, 1)
                            inspection_definition = sht.Cells(r, 4)
                            inspection_short_name = sht.Cells(r, 2)
                            lead = Trim(Str(start_index)) & "." & Trim(Str(Category)) & "." & Trim(Str(r - 1))
                            .Style = wdStyleHeading3

                            .TypeText lead & " " & inspection_name & " (" & inspection_short_name & ")"
                            
                            .TypeParagraph
                            .TypeText inspection_definition
                            .TypeParagraph
                            
                        End If
                    Next r
                    .TypeParagraph
                End If
            Next sht
            
        End With
        '.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 "C:\Projects\4803_GAIT\Inspections Description Revisions\inspections.docx"
        '.ActiveDocument.Close
        '.Quit
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You are confusing "headers", the area above the top margin, and "headings". You can easily find the code you need just by going into Word and recording a macro whilst you apply the heading styles.

Comment: That's very helpful. I did that. I use .Style = ActiveDocument("Heading 1") , but now it errors out "Class does not support Automation or does not support expected Interface" I wonder if there's an additional reference I need to include.

Comment: That should be `.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1")`, or, if you have set a reference to the Word library, you can use `.Style = wdStyleHeading1`

Comment: Ah...yes, I did figure that out ... I was coming back to replace the code with the working stuff, but I had to google a bit. Very, very helpful. tx.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Migrating solution from the question to an answer:</sub>

> Note: This question was [answered in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73306107/creating-a-word-document-from-excel-adding-headings#comment129462032_73306107) by Timothy Rylatt.
> The code at bottom is what I want. So that's the answer. Of interest
> to me is how I got to the answer.
>
> The big hint was following up on Timothy's comment below: Use Record Macro
> to figure out the call. I needed to add the Developer Ribbon to do
> that. (File --> options --> Customize Ribbon  ... then scroll down and
> select Developer) ... That adds the Developer Tab.
>
> Go to new developer tab, click record macro, go back to main text,
> select a word. Go to Home tab, select "Heading 1" for example, then go
> back to developer tab and click "stop recording." select "macros" and
> whatever name you gave the macros and edit.
>
> Slightly tricky part. It records:
>
> ```
> Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1")
> ```
>
> That won't work for some reason, so I googled "excel
> activedocument.styles"  That took me to this page:
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.styles
>
> The next hint was I saw the term wdStyleHeading1. The exact code there
> also does not work. I just experimented around until I got something
> that works. On the other hand, Timothy had typed the answer.